# How to use external libraries in grafana datasource-plugin

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, npm, grafana

how can I use a external library in a grafana datasource plugin?

My plugin works but when i require the "mqtt" library which I have installed and saved to the package.json file I get the following error:

Plugin Error
Error loading http://localhost:3000/public/mqtt as "mqtt" from http://localhost:3000/public/plugins/myfirstplug/datasource.js

```
this is what my datasource.js head looks like:

define([
  'mqtt'
  'angular',
  'lodash',
  '../core_module',
  'app/core/config',
],
function (mqtt,angular, _, coreModule, config) {
  'use strict';
```

As I said the package.json already includes mqtt as dependency and ive put the mqtt folder in almost every folder which may be used as library folder manually , too.

How can I use a npm library in a grafana datasource plugin so that it works?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I decided to bundle up the plugin and npm modules into a single js.

Comment: Haha nice approach, can you send me an example of how it looks like?
Is it easy to put all the dependencies into a single file? Like the mqtt dependency?

Comment: Grafana uses `SystemJS` as the module loader.  I did bundling using `systemjs-build` successfully. I will post a sample project later.

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same issue with including additional dependency for my plugin. I used [this experimental plugin](https://github.com/NatelEnergy/grafana-plotly-panel/) as boilerplate to tackle this issue:

1. You need to create a folder: `src/external/`
2. Add the compiled single file dist versions of your dependency under this folder like `src/external/mqtt.js`. (Actually even Grafana project has [vendors](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/tree/master/public/vendor) in git repository)
3. In build task, you need to copy the files under your `external` folder, so your `Gruntfile.js` should be like this: https://github.com/NatelEnergy/grafana-plotly-panel/blob/master/Gruntfile.js

   ```
   ...

   copy: {
     ...
     externals: {
       cwd: 'src',
       expand: true,
       src: ['**/external/*'],
       dest: 'dist'
     }
     ...
   },

   ...

   grunt.registerTask('default', ['clean', 'copy:src_to_dist', 'copy:pluginDef', 'copy:img_to_dist', 'copy:externals', 'babel']);
   ```
4. Now you can import the external library: `import * as mqtt from './external/mqtt';`

Comment: This worked great for me for angular based plugins. Also, how do you guys compile it into a single js file?
Does anyone know of a newer approach to do this with the React based datasource plugins?